# Should the Models deal with the request / response objects?

Tags: google-app-engine, model-view-controller, webapp2

For keeping my controllers thin and lean, I put all the logic to the models. But since I need read and set cookies, the models need to have the *request* and *response* objects. And now every time I call a model method, I *have to send* these objects as the arguments. I need to remember which method needs one object or another or both. It looks like:

> Model.handle_something(data, **self.request**, **self.response**)

Is is a right approach or there is a simpler way?

Comment: In my opinion you should never be doing that.  However you haven't provided enough information to show alternative approaches that would suit what you are doing.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do something like MVC, but you're moving your controller into your model.  Which is kinda breaking the philosophy behind MVC.  In general, you should probably keep cookie management separate from your models.

Comment: @dragonx: But cookie handling is part of the logic. I do some changes in the database and some corresponding changes in the cookies. I'm under impression that a controller is glue between a model and a view, so it should not do any logic.

Comment: Model in MVC should not be a class or object. Model is a layer. Cookies, from viewpoint of MVC, are form of storage. Which means that they would be handled by some sort of [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). Also, controller is not really a glue. It should only alter the state of model layer and current view(s) based on users input(usually, abstracted as some request object). Controller does not collect information from model layer. *Please, stop confusing MVC with Rails-like implementations (which are bastardizations of PAC)!*

Answer (score 0):

I will agree with the comments so far and suggest this is probably not the best way. Look for some way to abstract further what you need to do with the cookies. Possibly pass in a callback function or some other object that helps you maintain the separation you desire.

Comment: But a model has to touch the *response* object to set a cookie, it means I have to pass this object to the model anyhow. Since the controller owns this object in the first place--the controller has to send it to a model as an argument.

Comment: lambda state: request.cookies['mycookie'] = state

of course adjusting for whatever syntax your web framework is using. Or you could pass in an object MyStateController if things are more involved. The bottom line is that you want to avoid the **concept** of "setting a cookie" in your model. And of course if you are avoiding the concept, you want to avoid the associated objects (request, cookie, session ...) Feel free to post some code to get into more detail.